# Use WinForm as AppService for UWP

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I'm trying to figure out how I can send data to my WinForm Component without always having to reply on a message sent by the WinForm. I know one can set an AppService name, etc. in the `package.appxmanifest` of the UWP App. But, what is the equivaliant of this in a Win32 environment like WinForms.

Is any code needed to assist with getting an answer?

Thank you

**Edit**

Currently, my UWP App is responding to messages sent from my WinForm Component every couple of milliseconds.

`App.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
    if (args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails is AppServiceTriggerDetails)
    {
        appServiceDeferral = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
        args.TaskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled; // Associate a cancellation handler with the background task.

        AppServiceTriggerDetails details = args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
        Connection = details.AppServiceConnection;
        Connection.RequestReceived += (new MainPage()).Connection_OnRequestReceived; 
    }
}
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public async void Connection_OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // write setting to stop timer
    localSettings.Values["Win32Working"] = "True";

    // read content
    if (args.Request.Message.ContainsKey("content"))
    {
        object message = null;
        args.Request.Message.TryGetValue("content", out message);
        // if message is an int[]
        if (message is int[])
        {
            // init field vars
            int indexInArray = 0;
            bool newTest1On = false;
            bool newTest2On = false;
            bool newTest3On = false;

            foreach (int trueorfalse in (int[])message)
            {
                // set bool state based on index
                switch (indexInArray)
                {
                    case 0:
                        newCapsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse);
                        localSettings.Values["Test1"] = (Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse)).ToString();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        newNumOn = Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse);
                        localSettings.Values["Test2"] = (Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse)).ToString();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        newScrollOn = Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse);
                        localSettings.Values["Test3"] = (Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse)).ToString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                indexInArray++;
            }

            if (newTest1On != Test1On || newTest2On != Test2On || newTest3On != Test3On)
                localSettings.Values["updateUI"] = true.ToString();

            // update bools
            Test1On = newTest1On;
            Test2On = newTest2On;
            Test3On = neTest3On;

            // if exit requested
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["sendExit"]))
            {
                // tell WinForm to exit
                ValueSet messageExit = new ValueSet();
                messageExit.Add("exit", null);
                AppServiceResponseStatus responseStatus = await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(messageExit);
                localSettings.Values["sendExit"] = false.ToString();
                localSettings.Values["Win32Working"] = false.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (args.Request.Message.ContainsKey("request"))
    {
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["sendExit"]))
        {
            // send current settings as response
            AppServiceResponseStatus responseStatus = await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(UpdateWin32());
        }
        else
        {
            // tell WinForm to exit
            ValueSet message = new ValueSet();
            message.Add("exit", null);
            AppServiceResponseStatus responseStatus = await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(message);
            localSettings.Values["sendExit"] = false.ToString();
            localSettings.Values["Win32Working"] = false.ToString();
        }
    }
    else if (args.Request.Message.ContainsKey("exit"))
    {
        // exit
        Application.Current.Exit();
    }
}
```

My WinForm Code:

```
private async void threadCommunicationWinFrmAndUWP_Run()
{
    bool askForInfo = false;

    DoWork:

    ValueSet message = new ValueSet();
    if (!askForInfo) { message.Add("content", notifyIconsLogic.GetStatuses()); askForInfo = true; }
    else { message.Add("request", ""); askForInfo = false; }

    #region SendToUWP

    // if connection isn't inited
    if (connection == null)
    {
        // init
        connection = new AppServiceConnection();
        connection.PackageFamilyName = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
        connection.AppServiceName = "NotifyIconsUWP";

        // attempt connection 
        AppServiceConnectionStatus connectionStatus = await connection.OpenAsync();

        // if UWP isn't running
        if (connectionStatus == AppServiceConnectionStatus.AppUnavailable) return;
    }

    AppServiceResponse serviceResponse = await connection.SendMessageAsync(message);

    // if UWP isn't running
    if (serviceResponse.Status == AppServiceResponseStatus.Failure) return;

    // get response
    if (serviceResponse.Message.ContainsKey("content"))
    {
        object newMessage = null;
        serviceResponse.Message.TryGetValue("content", out newMessage);
        // if message is an int[]
        if (newMessage is int[])
        {
            // init field vars
            int indexInArray = 0;
            bool showTest1 = false;
            bool showTest2 = false;
            bool showTest3 = false;

            foreach (int trueorfalse in (int[])newMessage)
            {
                // set bool state based on index
                switch (indexInArray)
                {
                    case 0:
                        showTest1 = Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        showTest2 = Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        showTest3 = Convert.ToBoolean(trueorfalse);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                indexInArray++;
            }

            notifyIconsLogic.SetChecker(showTest1, showTest2, showTest3);
        }
    }
    if (serviceResponse.Message.ContainsKey("exit")) Exit();
    #endregion

    goto DoWork;
}
```

This ramps up the CPU Usage excessively. The point is, my only way of getting information to the WinForm from the UWP App, currently, is by responding to messages sent in a loop.

**Question**

How can I send messages from the UWP App to the WinForm without only responding to the messages sent in a loop? Because, I want to eliminate the reliance on the loop (CPU Purposes).

In other words: how do I get the results of the `package.appxmanifest` to 'work' in WinForms?

`package.appxmanifest`

```
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
      <uap:AppService Name="NotifyIconsUWP" />
    </uap:Extension>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Win32\NotifyIconsComponent.exe" />
</Extensions>
```

Comment: Are you looking for hosting a WFC service or WEB API service in an application (Windows Applictaion/Console Application/Windows Service)?

Comment: No, it's just a normal WinForm that I use to display NotifyIcons in the System Tray.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please edit the question and add some more details and elaborate more.

Comment: Please see my edit and tell me if you are still not understanding

Comment: Any Ideas guys?

Comment: Have you check this [blog](https://stefanwick.com/category/uwp-features-samples/page/2/)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send a request on the established app service connection from UWP app like this:

```
AppServiceResponse response = await App.Connection.SendMessageAsync(valueSet);
```

And then receive this message in the Windows Forms app by attaching an event handler:

```
connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;
```

Check out [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample) which demonstrates two way communication between Console app and UWP app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed the logic of the sample and got the connection established. But when i call SendMessageAsync , the code just pass by it without doing anything. No errors and no responses. i tried to open the connection but it returned to me that the connection is already opened AppServiceConnectionStatus connectionStatus = await App.Connection.OpenAsync();

Comment: Is it possible that i didn't implement Connection_RequestReceived on the Winforms app correctly? still i should get an error or some notification.

Comment: I have an issue where if i received any message from the Win32 app, i will not be able to send the messages from the UWP app. The UWP app will just lag and stop working. Can someone please advise me on that?

Comment: If you create a simple repo on GitHub, I can try to try it out and debug